# How do you create Users in a non default database?

Tags: python, database, django

I was reading over the docs and have my second database sync'd and ready to go. I find the section on telling django what database it should use by using the `.using('database')`.

On that same line of thought I tried to show django where it should save a User once it is created like thi:

```
User.objects.using('user_data').create_user(username=username, password=password, email='')
```

When I tried that bit of code out I got this error:

```
AttributeError at /signup/

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'create_user'
```

So I'm just curious if there is a different way I have to tell django that I want it saved in user_data and not the default db? I'd prefer not to use a router as i find them to be pretty confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'create_user'`, according to the documentation of [Using managers with multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases):

> For example, say you have a custom manager method that touches the
>   database -- User.objects.create_user(). Because create_user() is a
>   manager method, not a QuerySet method, **you can't do
>   User.objects.using('new_users').create_user()**. (The create_user()
>   method is only available on User.objects, the manager, not on QuerySet
>   objects derived from the manager.)

Emphasis mine. You need to do this:

```
User.objects.db_manager('new_users').create_user(username=username, password=password, email='')
```

Also, you can try this (haven't tested):

```
new_user = User()
new_user.username = username
new_user.password = password
new_user.email = ''
new_user.save(using='user_data')
```

More info for [Selecting a database for save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) in Django's documentation.

Comment: So how would I go about using Authincate()? or login()? or logout() too i guess. i tried the three methods that were in the docs and none of them seem to give the desired result. using: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password,using='user_data')` doesn't return a error but it also doesn't give the desired effect

Answer (score 2):

`.using('database')` returns a queryset, so you use this function to only get a query. In case of using create(), you have to use it via db_manager() like this:

```
User.objects.db_manager('database').create_user(...)
```

Take a look at: [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) for more information.